# Android auto connect to Bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, intentfilter

I want my android app to automatically connect to a paired BlueTooth device as soon as this device is powered on. Right now I do it by checking every second, whether the device is in range or not but I hope there is a better way?

For example, can I register a receiver, which is executed as soon as a Bluetooth device is in range? (like with BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, but not for the connected-event but for a „in range“ event)